# Rufus Scheduler - Help Starting / Stopping Jobs in Model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rufus-scheduler

After Reading the Rufus Scheduler Docs about 100 times, every StackOverflow question I can find, looking at the source code, and finally reading [how to report bugs effectively](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html) twice. I have come to the point where @jmettraux I need your help:

#### The Application

I am writing an internal application that allows my team to create metrics that periodically run code that saves values to a database. I have the following setup.

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "metrics", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "frequency"
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "data"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.enter code hereboolean  "active"
  end
```

**initializers/scheduler.rb**

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

class Rufus::Scheduler::Job
  def report
    logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.info "Job: #{@id} Tags: #{@tags} Frequency: #{@frequency}"
  end
end

SCHEDULER = Rufus::Scheduler.new(:lockfile => ".rufus-scheduler.lock")

unless defined?(Rails::Console) || File.split($0).last == 'rake'
  #Launch All Matrics Jobs that are active
  @metrics = Metric.active

  unless SCHEDULER.down?
    @metrics.each_with_index do | metric, index |
      SCHEDULER.every metric.frequency, :tags => metric.id, :overlap => false, :timeout => metric.try(:timeout) || '3m' do | job |
        metric.add_value
        job.report
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### What Works

The code above works flawlessly and Rufus initializes properly and all the jobs start as they should.

#### The Problem

Where I am running into a problem is that once the app is running I need to be able to unschedule jobs and reschedule them when a Metric is saved. I use the Rufus tags to assign a tag with the ID of the Metric when they are created and I'm using that to load them for unscheduling. 
Here is my current metric model with the relevant code.

**models/metric.rb**

```
class Metric < ApplicationRecord

  ...

  after_save :update_job

  private
  def update_job
    if self.changed.present?
      job = SCHEDULER.jobs(tag: self.id).first
      if job.present?
        logger.info "Job #{job.id}, for Metric #{self.id} unscheduled."
        SCHEDULER.unschedule(job.id)
      end

      if self.active
        metric = self
        new_job = SCHEDULER.every self.frequency, :tags => self.id, :overlap => false, :timeout => self.try(:timeout) || '3m' do | job |
          metric.add_value
        end
        logger.info "Job #{new_job} for Metric #{self.id} scheduled."
      end
    end
  end

end
```

#### The Actual Question!

> Scenario 1:
>
> - Application Starts
> - scheduler initilizer loads all active metrics
> - scheduler initilizer starts all active metrics as 'every' job
> - User edits an active metric setting it to inactive
> - The update_job method is ran after the metric is saved
> - inside the update_job method the job for the current metric is found successfully
> - the unscheudle method is called on the job
> - PROBLEM HERE: The job runs again even after being unscheduled
>
> Scenario 2:
>
> - Application Starts
> - scheduler initilizer loads all active metrics
> - scheduler initilizer starts all active metrics as 'every' job
> - User edits an inactive metric setting it to active
> - The update_job method is ran after the metric is saved
> - inside the update_job method a new 'every' job is scheduled for the metric
> - PROBLEM HERE: The job never gets started

#### What I have tried

- I have tried adding the following code to the bottom of the initializer to ensure that the unschedule method works properly in my app.

  ```
  sleep 50
  job = SCHEDULER.jobs(tag: 2).first
  SCHEDULER.unschedule(job)
  ```

  The Metric with ID 2 has a frequency of 20s. It runs twice then gets unscheduled correctly so I know its working properly outside of the model code.

#### System/Application Info

- Ruby 2.3.0
- Rails 5.0.0.1
- Puma 3.6.0
- OSX 10.12.1 Sierra
- rufus-scheduler 3.2.2

#### Phase 2 Logs - 12/20/2016

Scenario 1:

```
  xxx SCHEDULER started: 70168058449780
  xxx trigger (scheduled in initializer) Job: Rufus::Scheduler::EveryJob every_1482273018.01852_1684784125738549751 (70168045492220) Tags: ["2"] Frequency: 20.0
  xxx Metric 2 #update_job active: false
  xxx Metric 2 #update_job 0 SCHEDULER Rufus::Scheduler 3.2.2 70168058449780 down? false at_jobs: 0 in_jobs: 0 every_jobs: 2 interval_jobs: 0 cron_jobs: 0
  xxx Metric 2 found Job Job: Rufus::Scheduler::EveryJob every_1482273018.01852_1684784125738549751 (70168045492220) Tags: ["2"] Frequency: 20.0
  xxx Metric 2 Job every_1482273018.01852_1684784125738549751 unscheduled
  xxx Metric 2 #update_job 1 SCHEDULER Rufus::Scheduler 3.2.2 70168058449780 down? false at_jobs: 0 in_jobs: 0 every_jobs: 1 interval_jobs: 0 cron_jobs: 0
  xxx Metric 2 #update_job 2 SCHEDULER Rufus::Scheduler 3.2.2 70168058449780 down? false at_jobs: 0 in_jobs: 0 every_jobs: 1 interval_jobs: 0 cron_jobs: 0
  xxx trigger (scheduled in initializer) Job: Rufus::Scheduler::EveryJob every_1482273018.01852_1684784125738549751 (70168045492220) Tags: ["2"] Frequency: 20.0
  xxx trigger (scheduled in initializer) Job: Rufus::Scheduler::EveryJob every_1482273018.01852_1684784125738549751 (70168045492220) Tags: ["2"] Frequency: 20.0
```

Scenario 2:

```
  xxx SCHEDULER started: 70272158805840
  xxx Metric 2 #update_job active: true
  xxx Metric 2 #update_job 0 SCHEDULER Rufus::Scheduler 3.2.2 70272158805840 down? false at_jobs: 0 in_jobs: 0 every_jobs: 1 interval_jobs: 0 cron_jobs: 0
  xxx Metric 2 #update_job 1 SCHEDULER Rufus::Scheduler 3.2.2 70272158805840 down? false at_jobs: 0 in_jobs: 0 every_jobs: 1 interval_jobs: 0 cron_jobs: 0
  xxx Metric 2 Job every_1482273159.799382_1489585858424637616 scheduled
  xxx Metric 2 #update_job 2 SCHEDULER Rufus::Scheduler 3.2.2 70272158805840 down? false at_jobs: 0 in_jobs: 0 every_jobs: 2 interval_jobs: 0 cron_jobs: 0
```

#### Phase 3 Logs - 12/20/2016

Scenario 1:

```
xxx SCHEDULER started: 70321240613760
xxx sc Rufus::Scheduler 3.2.2 70321240613760
xxx sc down? false
xxx sc Process.pid 39975
xxx sc jobs:
xxx sc   0: j: Rufus::Scheduler::EveryJob i: "every_1482335616.453129_4198855636205920237" oi: 70321198587560 ts: ["2"] frq: 20.0 ua: nil c: 0 nt: 2016-12-21 09:53:56 -0600
xxx initializer over.
xxx Metric 2 Job every_1482335616.453129_4198855636205920237 scheduled in initializer for Metric 2
xxx Metric 2 Job every_1482335616.453129_4198855636205920237 scheduled in initializer for Metric 2
xxx Metric 2 Job every_1482335616.453129_4198855636205920237 scheduled in initializer for Metric 2
xxx Metric 2 #update_job changed: ["active", "updated_at"] active: false
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 0 Rufus::Scheduler 3.2.2 70321240613760
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 0 down? false
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 0 Process.pid 40037
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 0 jobs:
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 0   0: j: Rufus::Scheduler::EveryJob i: "every_1482335616.453129_4198855636205920237" oi: 70321198587560 ts: ["2"] frq: 20.0 ua: nil c: 0 nt: 2016-12-21 09:53:56 -0600
xxx Metric 2 found Job j: Rufus::Scheduler::EveryJob i: "every_1482335616.453129_4198855636205920237" oi: 70321198587560 ts: ["2"] frq: 20.0 ua: nil c: 0 nt: 2016-12-21 09:53:56 -0600 first
xxx Metric 2 Job every_1482335616.453129_4198855636205920237 unscheduled
xxx Metric 2 Job every_1482335616.453129_4198855636205920237 scheduled? false
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 1 Rufus::Scheduler 3.2.2 70321240613760
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 1 down? false
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 1 Process.pid 40037
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 1 jobs:
xxx Metric 2 Job every_1482335616.453129_4198855636205920237 scheduled in initializer for Metric 2
```

Scenario 2:

```
xxx SCHEDULER started: 70152969118240
xxx sc Rufus::Scheduler 3.2.2 70152969118240
xxx sc down? false
xxx sc Process.pid 40811
xxx sc jobs:
xxx initializer over.
xxx Metric 2 #update_job changed: ["active", "updated_at"] active: true
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 0 Rufus::Scheduler 3.2.2 70152969118240
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 0 down? false
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 0 Process.pid 40872
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 0 jobs:
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 1 Rufus::Scheduler 3.2.2 70152969118240
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 1 down? false
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 1 Process.pid 40872
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 1 jobs:
xxx Metric 2 Job every_1482336051.9823449_3069051954259909338 scheduled in #update_job
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 2 Rufus::Scheduler 3.2.2 70152969118240
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 2 down? false
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 2 Process.pid 40872
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 2 jobs:
xxx Metric 2 sc #update_job 2   0: j: Rufus::Scheduler::EveryJob i: "every_1482336051.9823449_3069051954259909338" oi: 70152971745840 ts: ["2"] frq: 20.0 ua: nil c: 0 nt: 2016-12-21 10:01:11 -0600
```

Comment: OK, you're using Puma, so you have a single Ruby process. Quick request for test. Does the problem persist if you stop using the lockfile? In other words, does the problem persist if you simply do `SCHEDULER = Rufus::Scheduler.new` ?

Comment: @jmettraux I tried removing the lockfile and unfortunately the problem remains.

Comment: Added phase 2 to answer below

Comment: @jmettraux Added logs from phase 2 code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Added phase 3 to answer below. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Added phase 3 logs to question. It looks like some how there is a new scheduler process that is subsequently created and then destroyed inside the model code. Thanks again for your diligence on this!

Comment: Added phase 4 to my answer below.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the above code runs for an active metric going inactive I successfully get the Logger messages and load the right job. As well, when I use better errors to inspect the code at that area the job itself sets the @unscheduled_at attribute correctly however the Job keeps getting rescheduled to run again.
>
> On the other side of it when the update_job method runs and is trying to reschedule the job it never starts.

So are you trying to say that the Job gets rescheduled but that new, rescheduled, Job is never triggering?

If I naively look at your code (rehashed it for a better understanding):

```
def update_job

  if self.changed.present?
    job = SCHEDULER.jobs(tag: self.id).first
    if job.present?
      logger.info "Job #{job.id}, for Metric #{self.id} unscheduled."
      job.unschedule
    end

    if self.active
      metric = self
      new_job_id =
        SCHEDULER.every(
          self.frequency,
          :tags => self.id,
          :overlap => false,
          :timeout => self.try(:timeout) || '3m'
        ) { |job| metric.add_value }
      logger.info "Job #{new_job_id} for Metric #{self.id} scheduled."
    end
  end
end
```

Could the symptom you describe be resumed to "application never enters the reschedule block of the update_job method"?

> The Metric with ID 2 has a frequency of 20s. It runs twice then gets unscheduled correctly so I know its working properly outside of the model code.

So it's something in your code model. There is a small chance that it's related with rufus-scheduler.

Please rephrase carefully your "actual question". In its current version, it is confusing me.

**phase 2 - 2016-12-21**

Could you please try with the code below?

Warning: it is not tested, it may contain errors you'll certainly spot and fix to make it usable.

Then try your two scenarii and report, with a log grep of the "xxx " this code is emitting. It might tell us what is going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
# initializers/scheduler.rb

require 'rufus-scheduler'

class Rufus::Scheduler
  def to_report_s
    a = []
    a << self.class
    a << Rufus::Scheduler::VERSION
    a << self.object_id
    a << "down? #{self.down?}"
    %w[ at in every internal cron ].each do |flav|
      m = "#{flav}_jobs".to_sym
      a << "#{m}: #{self.send(m).size}"
    end
    a.collect(&:to_s).join(' ')
  end
end
class Rufus::Scheduler::Job
  def to_report_s
    "Job: #{self.class} #{@id} (#{self.object_id}) " +
    "Tags: #{@tags.inspect} Frequency: #{@frequency}"
  end
end

#SCHEDULER = Rufus::Scheduler.new(:lockfile => ".rufus-scheduler.lock")
SCHEDULER = Rufus::Scheduler.new

# Add "global" error handler to the rufus-scheduler instance
#
def SCHEDULER.on_error(job, error)

  Rails.logger.error(
    "xxx err#{error.object_id} rufus-scheduler intercepted #{error.inspect}" +
    " in job #{job.to_report_s}")
  error.backtrace.each_with_index do |line, i|
    Rails.logger.error(
      "xxx err#{error.object_id} #{i}: #{line}")
  end
end

logger.info("xxx SCHEDULER started: #{SCHEDULER.object_id}")

unless (
  defined?(Rails::Console) || File.split($0).last == 'rake' ||
  SCHEDULER.down?
)
  # launch All Matrics Jobs that are active

  Metric.active.each do |metric|

    SCHEDULER.every(
      metric.frequency,
      :tags => metric.id,
      :overlap => false,
      :timeout => metric.try(:timeout) || '3m'
    ) do |job|
      logger.info "xxx trigger (scheduled in initializer) #{job.to_report_s}"
      metric.add_value
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
# models/metric.rb

class Metric < ApplicationRecord

  after_save :update_job

  private

  def update_job

    lip = "Metric #{id}" # logger info prefix
    logger.info("xxx #{lip} #update_job active: #{self.active.inspect}")

    if self.changed.present?

      logger.info("xxx #{lip} #update_job 0 SCHEDULER #{SCHEDULER.to_report_s}")

      #job = SCHEDULER.jobs(tag: self.id).first
      #if job.present?
      if job = SCHEDULER.jobs(tag: self.id).first
        logger.info "xxx #{lip} found Job #{job.to_report_s}"
        #SCHEDULER.unschedule(job.id)
        job.unschedule
        logger.info "xxx #{lip} Job #{job.id} unscheduled"
      end

      logger.info("xxx #{lip} #update_job 1 SCHEDULER #{SCHEDULER.to_report_s}")

      if self.active
        metric = self
        job_id = SCHEDULER.every(
          self.frequency,
          :tags => self.id,
          :overlap => false,
          :timeout => self.try(:timeout) || '3m'
        ) do |job|
          logger.info "xxx trigger (scheduled in #updateJob) #{job.to_report_s}"
          metric.add_value
        end
        logger.info "xxx #{lip} Job #{job_id} scheduled"
      end

      logger.info("xxx #{lip} #update_job 2 SCHEDULER #{SCHEDULER.to_report_s}")
    end
  end
end
```

**phase 3 - 2016-12-21**

Could you please retry with the code below:

```
# initializers/scheduler.rb

require 'rufus-scheduler'

class Rufus::Scheduler
  def to_report_a
    a = []
    a << "#{self.class} #{Rufus::Scheduler::VERSION} #{object_id}"
    a << "down? #{self.down?}"
    a << "Process.pid #{Process.pid}"
    a << "jobs:"
    jobs.each_with_index { |job, i| a << "  #{i}: #{job.to_report_s}" }
    a.collect(&:to_s)
  end
end
class Rufus::Scheduler::Job
  def to_report_s
    {
      j: self.class, i: @id, oi: object_id, ts: @tags,
      frq: @frequency, ua: @unscheduled_at, c: count, nt: next_time
    }
      .collect { |k, v| "#{k}: #{v.inspect}" }
      .join(' ')
  end
end

#SCHEDULER = Rufus::Scheduler.new(:lockfile => ".rufus-scheduler.lock")
SCHEDULER = Rufus::Scheduler.new

# Add "global" error handler to the rufus-scheduler instance
#
def SCHEDULER.on_error(job, error)
  lep = "xxx err#{error.object_id}"
  Rails.logger.error(
    "xxx #{lep} rufus-scheduler intercepted #{error.inspect}" +
    " in job #{job.to_report_s}")
  error.backtrace.each_with_index do |line, i|
    Rails.logger.error(
      "xxx #{lep} #{i}: #{line}")
  end
  Rails.logger.error("xxx #{lep} scheduler:")
  SCHEDULER.to_report_a.each { |l| Rails.logger.error("xxx #{lep} #{l}") }
end

logger.info("xxx SCHEDULER started: #{SCHEDULER.object_id}")

unless (
  defined?(Rails::Console) || File.split($0).last == 'rake' ||
  SCHEDULER.down?
)
  # launch All Matrics Jobs that are active

  Metric.active.each do |metric|

    lip = "Metric #{metric.id}" # logger info prefix

    job_id =
      SCHEDULER.every(
        metric.frequency,
        :tags => metric.id,
        :overlap => false,
        :timeout => metric.try(:timeout) || '3m'
      ) do |job|
        logger.info(
          "xxx #{lip} trigger (scheduled in initializer) " +
          "#{job.to_report_s}")
        metric.add_value
      end
    logger.info(
      "xxx #{lip} Job #{job_id} scheduled in initializer " +
      "for Metric #{metric.id}")
  end

  SCHEDULER.to_report_a.each { |l| logger.info("xxx sc #{l}") }
  logger.info("xxx initializer over.")
end
```

and

```
# models/metric.rb

class Metric < ApplicationRecord

  after_save :update_job

  private

  def update_job

    lip = "Metric #{id}" # logger info prefix
    logger.info(
      "xxx #{lip} #update_job " +
      "changed: #{self.changed.inspect} active: #{self.active.inspect}")

    return unless self.changed.present?

    SCHEDULER.to_report_a
      .each { |l| logger.info("xxx #{lip} sc #update_job 0 #{l}") }

    jobs = SCHEDULER.jobs(tag: self.id)

    jobs.each_with_index do |job, i|
      logger.info(
        "xxx #{lip} found Job #{job.to_report_s} #{i == 0 ? 'first' : ''}")
    end

    if job = jobs.first
      #SCHEDULER.unschedule(job.id)
      job.unschedule
      logger.info "xxx #{lip} Job #{job.id} unscheduled"
      logger.info "xxx #{lip} Job #{job.id} scheduled? #{SCHEDULER.scheduled?(job.id)}"
    end

    SCHEDULER.to_report_a
      .each { |l| logger.info("xxx #{lip} sc #update_job 1 #{l}") }

    return unless self.active

    metric = self
    job_id = SCHEDULER.every(
      self.frequency,
      :tags => self.id,
      :overlap => false,
      :timeout => self.try(:timeout) || '3m'
    ) do |job|
      logger.info "xxx trigger (scheduled in #update_job) #{job.to_report_s}"
      metric.add_value
    end
    logger.info "xxx #{lip} Job #{job_id} scheduled in #update_job"

    SCHEDULER.to_report_a
      .each { |l| logger.info("xxx #{lip} sc #update_job 2 #{l}") }
  end
end
```

**phase 4 - 2016-12-22**

> Added phase 3 logs to question. It looks like some how there is a new scheduler process that is subsequently created and then destroyed inside the model code. Thanks again for your diligence on this!

Is that really happening in the model code? Your logs tell us that it happens in another process. Your initial Ruby process instantiates rufus-scheduler then your HTTP requests are served in worker processes which are forks of your initial process (without the threads, in other words with inactive schedulers).

You're using Puma in clustered mode. I should have immediately asked you about your configuration.

Read carefully its documentation at https://github.com/puma/puma#configuration

An easy fix would be not to use the clustered mode so that there is only one Ruby process involved, serving all the HTTP requests.

On the other hand, if you need the clustered mode, you have to change your way of thinking. You probably don't want to have 1 rufus-scheduler instance per worker thread. You could focus on having the core (live) rufus-scheduler in the main process. It could have a "management" job that checks recently updated metrics and unschedules/schedules jobs.

```
SCHEDULER.every '10s', overlap: false do
  Metric.recently_updated.each do |metric|
    SCHEDULER.jobs(tags: metric.id).each(&:unschedule)
    SCHEDULER.every(metric.frequency, tags: self.id) { metric.add_value }
  end
end
  # or something like that...
```

Have fun!

Comment: I have rephrased the question to reflect the steps my application takes and where the problem I am encountering is actually happening. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I am going to accept this but real quick can you update your answer to also include what I finally ended up doing as an option. Your diagnosis as to the problem was correct rails 5 by default uses cluster mode and both of your solutions would work, but I wanted to leave puma in cluster mode but I didn't want a clean up job running all the time so instead I am using Redis pub/sub (which comes with rails 5 by default) to message the main process to stop jobs on metric update. Thanks for your help on this!!

Comment: Sorry, I do not want to update my answer with the option you chose. It is your option, not mine, adding it to my answer breaks the dialogue. I think it sits well in the comment above.